# Relationship between second order derivatives and cross derivative of smooth surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives

Probably a silly question, but I wonder if $z=f(x,y)$ is a smooth surface, and the values of its two second order derivatives $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}$ are known to be both positive throughout a region, say $0<x<1$, $0<y<1$, dose this place a restriction on the possible values of the cross derivative, i. e. $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}$ ?

The naive geometrical idea behind this is: if I cut a surface horizontally (parallel to the $x$-axis) or vertically (parallel to the $y$-axis) and always find an exponential (or other) curve, does this makes a random cut obliquely more likely to be a exponential-like (or other-like) curve ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "restriction on the possible values."  But maybe consider $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 + axy$, where $a$ is some real number.  Note that $f_{xx} = 2 > 0$ and $f_{yy} = 2 > 0$, whereas $f_{xy} = a$.  So, $f_{xy}$ could be positive, zero, or negative depending on the value of $a$.

Comment: @JesseMadnick Thanks! Very useful example, I misunderstood the geometric meaning of $f_{xy}$ in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your intuition is a bit off. The quantity $f_{xx}$  tells you about the shapes of cross-section curves lying in planes $y = \text{constant}$, as you said. Similarly, $f_{yy}$ tells you about cross-sections in a perpendicular direction. It seems that this ought to tell you something about oblique sections, I agree. But the flaw in your reasoning is to associate $f_{xy}$ with these oblique cross-sections. In fact, $f_{xy}$ tells you how the slopes of cross-section curves change as you move the sectioning plane. In other words, it tells you about *variation* of cross-sections, not about the cross-sections themselves.

There is a related theorem that might be of interest: [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_%28differential_geometry%29) tells you how the curvatures of planar sections vary as you rotate the sectioning plane around a surface normal. In fact, the curvature in any direction can be calculated very simply from the curvatures in two specific directions (called the principal directions) that happen to be perpendicular to each other. Not exactly what you had in mind, but in the same spirit, I think.

Comment: Thanks! Very useful and clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Your original question is not as far-fetched as you think. To elaborate on @Jesse Madnick's response, to understand the behavior (i.e., curvature) of the various cross-sections, you need *all* the Hessian matrix. That is, if the tangent plane to your surface is horizontal, the second-order Taylor polynomial is 
\begin{align*}
f(x,y) &= f(0,0) + Q(x,y)\,, \quad\text{where}\\
Q(x,y) &= \tfrac12\left(f_{xx}(0,0)x^2 + 2f_{xy}(0,0)xy + f_{yy}(0,0)y^2\right)\,.
\end{align*}
That is, the curvature of the slice in direction $\vec v$ is obtained by putting $\vec v$ into the quadratic form given by the Hessian matrix.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Now I can see that the two eigenvectors of the Hessian are the two principle directions mentioned in @bubba's answer.

Comment: That's right (almost) -- they are called "principal" directions, not "principle" directions.